# Settings statistics of users tracking at Angular 4

Tags: angular

I am working Angular 4, how can I  display the users tracking statistics of site on a weekly and monthly and Daily in
 the main page of Admin.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.Please post your code that you have tried.

Comment: You have to implement a system like this: https://github.com/saeed-m/WebSiteStatistics more info in Persian: https://www.dotnettips.info/projects/details/30

Answer (score 0):

You can use [google Analytics](https://www.google.com/analytics/)
go to Angular CLI :
`ng new google-analytics-using-angular --minimal`
then
`cd google-analytics-using-angular`

in index.html paste the Google Analytics tracking code below the  tag

```
<app-root></app-root>
<script>
  (function(i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
            i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
            i[r] = i[r] || function() {
                (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
            }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
            a = s.createElement(o),
                m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
            a.async = 1;
            a.src = g;
            m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
        })(window, document, 'script', 'https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');
ga('create', 'UA-109919601-1', 'auto');// add your tracking ID here.
ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

Serve the app  using `ng serve`
and just Open your Google Analytics dashboard!!

[here](https://github.com/revolunet/angular-google-analytics) is another Example code